# execute Yii2 console command from Yii2 extension with Craft

Tags: console, commands

Does anyone know if and how a console command from a Yii2 extension can be used with Craft?

To be more specific, I would like to use
https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-migration-creator
which is a yii2 extension providing a command to create migrations from existing tables.

However when I composer-require the extension, its command do not appear in Craft console command's list of commands.

Answer (score 1):

ok, found out how this works:

- it's not sufficient to composer-require the extension
- it needs to be activated. for bizley/migration this is done via controllerMap in e.g. app.php (see documentation)
- you can now create migrations for existing tables, but they are saved to Craft's vendor director (vendor/craftcms/cms/src/migrations/)
- since this is not the right place, I manually created a migration via Craft's console command, copied the code from vendor/craftcms/cms/src/migrations/, removed the automatically created migration and pasted it into the manually created one.